# django, reverse lookup in teams and employees having manytomany relationship

Tags: django, relationship

models.py (EDIT: added date fields to EmployeeConfig)

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)

class EmployeeConfig(models.Model):
    employee         = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region           = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    config_start_dt  = models.DateField(null=False)
    config_end_dt    = models.DateField(default=dt.datetime.strptime('31-Dec-2075',"%d-%b-%Y").date())
    live             = models.BooleanField() #only one config is live

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name   =   models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    employees   =   models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
```

Every employee can be part of multiple teams. I want to create context with queryset as employee_id, team_names, region (live config).

Questions:

1. Is the above structure correct for my usecase ?
2. How to write view to display "employee_id, region, team_names", for all employees, their corresponding live config and list of teams they are part of?

Comment: What's the point of the separate EmployeeConfig model? Why isn't that data directly on Employee?

Comment: Right now an `Employee` can have *multiple* `EmployeeConfig`s, is this wanted behavior?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i missed mentioning start_dt and end_dt in employeeconfig, idea is that we can change employee configs with time, keeping history of such changes. and only one such config is live. Should EmployeeConfig attributes be moved to Employee only ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes Willem, but only 1 live config, this is store historical changes in employee configs with time, i missed out on mentioning start_dt and end_dt attributes in EmployeeConfig